# Problem removing a character from char array

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I am writing a program to remove the character "&" from a char array if it exist and display the output.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void decrypt(char mess[1024])
{
    int i = 0;
    int decmp = 0;
    int len = strlen(mess);
    char decmess[256] = {0};
    while (i < len)
    {
        if (strcmp(&mess[i], "&") ==    0) {
            i++;
        } else {
            decmess[decmp] = mess[i];
            i++;
            decmp++;
        }
    }
    cout << decmess <<  endl;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char encmess[1024] = {0};
    cout << "Enter message to decrypt" << endl;
    cin.getline(encmess, 1024);
    decrypt(encmess);
}
```

But it just isnt working only "&" from last of the string is removed if exist.

Sample input/output:

```
input: sg&shx&f
output: sg&sh&f
```

```
input: dh&st&
output: dh&st
```

Please help!!!

Comment: strcmp(&mess[i], "&").
&mess[i] is an address of mess index i. Think it should be mess[i]

Comment: Change `if (strcmp(&mess[i], "&") == 0)` to `if (mess[i] =='&')`

Comment: If this is indeed a C++ question, use `<string>` and `<algorithm>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overly complicating things mixing `strlen()` and `char[]` and `#include <string>`. You rely on initialization without ever affirmatively nul-terminating `decmess`, you don't need `strcmp()` to compare a single character.

It appears you wanted to do:

```
#define MAXC 1024           /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

void decrypt(char *mess)
{
    char decmess[MAXC] = "";
    int i = 0, decmp = 0;
    
    for (; mess[i]; i++)
        if (mess[i] != '&')
            decmess[decmp++] = mess[i];
    
    decmess[decmp] = 0;     /* affirmatively nul-terminate despite initialization */
    
    std::cout << decmess << '\n';
}
```

(**note:** a C-string is *nul-terminated* there is no need to get the length before iterating over the characters it contains, just loop until you find the nul-character (ASCII 0). Also, `main()` taking no arguments is just `int main()` or `int main(void)`)

As to why what you did didn't work, `strcmp(&mess[i], "&")` compares `&` with whatever is left in `mess` starting at `mess + i` so you never match `'&'` alone. `&mess[i]` is simply a pointer to the i<sup>th</sup> character in `mess` and using `strcmp` compares from that position to end of string with `"&"`. (you can limit that with `strncmp(&mess[i], "&", 1)` -- but that is superfluous for `if (mess[i] == '&')`

Adding your short `main()` you would have:

```
#include <iostream>

#define MAXC 1024           /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

void decrypt(char *mess)
{
    char decmess[MAXC] = "";
    int i = 0, decmp = 0;
    
    for (; mess[i]; i++)
        if (mess[i] != '&')
            decmess[decmp++] = mess[i];
    
    decmess[decmp] = 0;     /* affirmatively nul-terminate despite initialization */
    
    std::cout << decmess << '\n';
}

int main(void)
{
    char encmess[MAXC] = "";
    
    std::cout << "Enter message to decrypt" << '\n';
    std::cin.getline(encmess, MAXC);
    
    decrypt(encmess);
}
```

(**note:** see: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/364696) and [C++: “std::endl” vs “\n”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n))

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/decmess
Enter message to decrypt
sg&shx&f
sgshxf
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Yeah, it works, and it fixed the error. I am new to programming so I write complicated stuff most of the time.

Comment: No problem, refinement comes with experience. Get it working first -- then work on refining `:)`

Comment: Sure `strcmp(&mess[i], "&"` compares `&` with whatever is left in `mess` starting at `mess + i` so you never match `'&'` (you could do `strncmp (&mess[i], "&", 1)` -- but why)

Answer (score 2):

Because you tagged your question with `c++` here is the c++-way of doing this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

void decrypt(std::string& mess)
{
    mess.erase(std::remove_if(mess.begin(), mess.end(), [](auto c) {return c == '&'; }), mess.end());
}
```